# Explode string in laravel blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new for laravel framework. I want to explode string and run foreach loop.
Here is my code, assume `$data->facing="Hello,World";`

```
@if ($data->facing != "")
@foreach($data->facings as $info)
<option>{{$info}}</option>
@endforeach
@endif
```

how to explode `$data->facing` using `","`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just simply explode, however this logic should come from your controller/model

```
@if ($data->facings != "")
  @foreach(explode(',', $data->facings) as $info) 
    <option>{{$info}}</option>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

If `$data` is some sort of model, I would suggest adding an accessor to your model

```
class MyModel extends Model 
{
  public function getFacingsAttribute()
  {
    return explode(',', $this->facings);
  }
}
```

Then you can simply treat it as an array, as per your original example.

```
@foreach($data->facings as $info)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use explode like this:

```
$new_array = array();
if($data->facing) { 
$new_array = explode(',',$data->facing);
}
@if (is_array($new_array) && count($new_array) > 0)
@foreach($new_array as $info)
<option>{{$info}}</option>
@endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Blades `@foreach` directive is just a wrapper around PHPs native `foreach`:

```
@foreach(explode(',', $data->facings) as $info)
    <option>{{ $info }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code and it works for me.

```
@foreach(explode(',', $data->facings) as $info)
    <option>{{ $info }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I am always used this way and solve the problem.

```
@foreach(explode(',', $data->facings) as $info)
<option>{{ $info }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: @foreach(explode(',', $data->facings) as $info)
    <option>{{ $info }}</option>
@endforeach

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).